# How to install libgsasl7_1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1~esm1 on 20.04 LTS?

Tags: lts, esm

We are now using ubuntu 20.04 LTS. One of them asked us to install libgsasl7_1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1~esm due to a vulnerability, but it is not an ESM and does not appear in the package that can be installed. Can we install this package without upgrading ubuntu to ESM even though we are using LTS?

Comment: The package is found in 'universe' which is **not** covered by security fixes without Pro, just as per all prior releases. Ubuntu/Canonical provide security fixes for packages found in 'main' only for all releases unless Ubuntu Pro is used which adds extra security.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!